# Convert queryBuilder result into associative array

Tags: php, symfony, doctrine-orm, query-builder

im looking for way, how to convert query builder result into associative array. But what I need is including relation data from another table.
If I use getArrayResult() method, it gives me an array, but without foreign keys. And I need foreign keys included with nested array with data of associative db table.
**EDIT:**
Here is my code:

```
$qb = $this->_em->createQueryBuilder();
$qb->select('p');
$qb->from('XXX\MyBundle\Entity\Entity1', 'p');

$qb->leftJoin('p.FK1','u');
$qb->andWhere('u.Attr1 = :attr1');
$qb->setParameter('attr1', $appId);
$qb->andWhere('u.Attr2 IS NULL');
$qb->leftJoin('u.FK2', 'v');
$qb->andWhere('v.Attr3 = :attr3');
$qb->andWhere('v.Attr4 IS NULL');
$qb->setParameter('attr3', $userId);


$result = $qb->getQuery()->getArrayResult();
```

I need this conversion becouse of SOAP. It could not return complex object as nested objects of entities.

Comment: Can you please show your request code ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, you need to write this function in your Entity1Repository.php

Since you're using the createQueryBuilder() method, you don't need to use select and from methods.
In your example, you're writing the joins, but you're not asking the query to return those joins.

Try this code :

```
<?php

namespace XXX\\MyBundle\Entity;

use Doctrine\ORM\EntityRepository;

class Entity1Repository extends EntityRepository
{
    public function getEntityWithJoins()
    {
        return $this
            ->createQueryBuilder('p')
            ->addSelect('u')
            ->addSelect('v')
            ->leftJoin('p.FK1','u')
            ->andWhere('u.Attr1 = :attr1')
            ->setParameter('attr1', $appId)
            ->andWhere('u.Attr2 IS NULL')
            ->leftJoin('u.FK2', 'v')
            ->andWhere('v.Attr3 = :attr3')
            ->andWhere('v.Attr4 IS NULL')
            ->setParameter('attr3', $userId);
            ->getQuery()
            ->getArrayResult();
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you so much. But there is next problem that it returns nested array only of one foreign key, but there are two FK`s in one table and the second one isn`t in array;

Comment: I got it... i have to create one more leftJoin, but i don`t know how, for second FK in table.

Comment: Just add the leftJoin and addSelect... What's the problem ?